# pthread_getspecific(key) get not NULL result, but not call pthread_setspecific(key), why?

Tags: c++, linux

.h file ：

```
class RedisThreadLocalClient { 
public: 
    RedisThreadLocalClient() {}
    virtual ~RedisThreadLocalClient(); 
public:
    static void destroy_client(void* client) {
        RedisSyncClient* c = static_cast<RedisSyncClient*>(client);
        delete c;
    }   

    static int init(const std::vector<std::string>& address) {
        _s_address = address;
        return pthread_key_create(&_s_thread_key, RedisThreadLocalClient::destroy_client);  
    }   

   static RedisSyncClient* get_client();

private: 
    static pthread_key_t _s_thread_key;  
    static std::vector<std::string> _s_address; 
};
```

.cc file

```
pthread_key_t RedisThreadLocalClient::_s_thread_key;
std::vector< std::string> RedisThreadLocalClient::_s_address;

RedisSyncClient* RedisThreadLocalClient::get_client()
{
    RedisSyncClient* client = static_cast<RedisSyncClient*>(pthread_getspecific(_s_thread_key));
    if (client != NULL) // HERE
    {
        return client;
    }

    RedisSyncClient* c = new RedisSyncClient();
    if (c->init(_s_address) != 0)
    {
        delete c;
        return NULL;
    }

    pthread_setspecific(_s_thread_key, c);
    return c;
}
```

Why is `if ( client != NULL )` evaluating as `true` when first called in this function? I thought if I haven't-yet called `pthread_setspecific` for the current thread, NULL would be returned from `pthread_getspecific` and therefore the result would be `false` ?

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `pthread_getspecific()` returning? When is `init()` called? (Also, in general it would be better if you could give a minimal, complete, verifiable example, see [the help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: This is a trivial bug: empty constructor doesn't call `init`.

Comment: @Kaz: I wouldn't assume that, it's possible that `init()` is called elsewhere before or after the class is instantiated.

Comment: @Hasturkun I find that I don't call the init() , thank you. could I close the question ?

Comment: @Hasturkun Indeed, looking more closely, this looks like a class-wide initialization. The program must call `RedisThreadLocalClient::init` once, not the constructor, which would be wrong.

Comment: That being said, this class doesn't make sense.  Non-static member functions do the get/set-specific, using a static key.  What is the point? If you multiply instantiate this class, it means all instances refer to the same key (the key that is created by the single call to `init`).    If it is forbidden to multiply instantiate this class, it still doesn't have to use a static variable for the key.     **Use a non-static variable for the key, and have the constructor acquire it with `pthread_key_create` instead of a static `init`)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_key_create` should be called precisely once, before any use of `pthread_getspecific` or `pthread_setspecific` with that key.

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_key_create.html:

> The `pthread_key_create()` call could either be explicitly made in a module initialization routine, or it can be done implicitly by the first call to a module [using `pthread_once`].